# How can I add a password to a base 64 pdf?

Tags: java, pdf, itext7

I have this method in which I add a password to the pdf, but I am doing it with pdf from the computer. What I want to try is to receive as input parameter a string that would be pdf in base 64 and respond to a base64.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
            try {

                OutputStream file = new FileOutputStream(new File("D:\\Test.pdf"));

            Document document = new Document();
            PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, file);

            writer.setEncryption(USER_PASS.getBytes(), OWNER_PASS.getBytes(),
                    PdfWriter.ALLOW_PRINTING, PdfWriter.ENCRYPTION_AES_128);

            document.open();
            document.add(new Paragraph("Hello World, iText"));
            document.add(new Paragraph(new Date().toString()));

            document.close();
            file.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It was complicated how to handle a Base64 pdf because it was the first time, but in the end I was able to develop the method where you can add the password to a pdf that is already in base64.

```
   public String EncriptarPDFconContraseña(String pdfBase64, String passwordUser, String passwordOwner) throws IOException, DocumentException {

        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(Base64.decode(pdfBase64));
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, baos);
        stamper.setEncryption(passwordUser.getBytes(), passwordOwner.getBytes(), PdfWriter.ALLOW_PRINTING, PdfWriter.ENCRYPTION_AES_128);
        stamper.close();
        String base64 = Base64.encodeBytes(baos.toByteArray());

        return base64;
    }
```